# Customize boostrap-vue in a Nuxt project

Tags: css, vue.js, bootstrap-4, nuxt.js

I have a **nuxt** project where I use [bootstrap-vue](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/) as a module to style my components.

I'm not happy with the default styles and I want to add a little bit of customization, to be more precise I want to change the **navbar** how it looks like and add some animation to the toggle button.

How should I access and change the **bootstrap css** files in my **nuxt** project ?

Anyone has any examples to share ?

Comment: The best way is create css to overwrite bootstrap.

Comment: Is there any way I can access bootstrap-vue css files so i can directly change the css properties ?

Comment: Who do you want to change directly? From experience, this causes a lot of trouble, because of the side effects.

Comment: I was assuming multiple code would be a mess, but you are right, the best way is to create css to overwrite bootstrap.

Comment: Just create CSS with name `bootstrap-custom` and @import ;) simple and better

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At first you should change your nuxt.config.js to

```
  bootstrapVue: {
    bootstrapCSS: false,
    bootstrapVueCSS: false
+  },
```

And add

```
css: ['~/assets/styles/bootstrap-custom.scss']
```

To it

After that in the  bootstrap-custom.scss define your style on top of bootstap css like this:

```
@import "base/vars";

$primary:       $fc-blue ;
$secondary:     #ffffff ;
$light:         #f1f1f1 ;
$dark:          $fc-black-gray ;

//then bootstrap & bootstrap-vue should be added after
//so that they inherit the custom SCSS variables
@import 'bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss';
@import 'bootstrap-vue/src/index.scss';
```

Answer (score 1):

Many of the styles, controlled by bootstrap V4.3 SCSS, can be modified (themed) by setting SCSS variables then compiling Bootstrap + BootstrapVue SCSS.

As mentioned in the comments above, you can also create custom styles/classes and apply those classes to the components you want to alter.

See the theming docs at https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/reference/theming